# Johansen test - full rank however variables are I(1)

Tags: stationarity, cointegration

I have a situation in which my Johansen cointegration test results indicate a full rank, rejecting both that there is no cointegrating vector as well as that there is at most one. I am working with two variables/price series.

Each of the series is clearly `I(1)` based on ADF-testing and PP-testing.

When using Johansen's test, I attain a matrix Π of full rank. According to literature this should imply that the underlying data is I(0). However as mentioned, the ADF and PP clearly stated that it is non-stationary.

How to resolve this situation?

Comment: One possible reason: your ADF tests only tell you that you cannot reject the null of nonstationarity. What they definitely do not do is show "clearly" that the series are I(1).

Comment: I am not sure about what you are saying @ChristophHanck, if the matrix is full rank it implies that you are rejectin the null hypothesis of 1 cointegration relationship and you are accepting the alternative hypothesis of two I(0) series, or at least that is what I understand, could you develop a bit your point?

Comment: Same as in other thread: the starting point test result that the series are "clearly" I(1) may have been a case of a type II error of falsely not rejecting the null of nonstationarity even though the series in fact are I(0).